# Google Cloud Vertex AI - 400 'dedicated_resources' is not supported for Model

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm attempting to deploy a text classification model I trained with Vertex AI on the Google Cloud Platform using the Python SDK.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "<key location>"

def create_endpoint(
    project_id: str,
    display_name: str,
    location: str,
    sync: bool = True,
):
    endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint.create(
        display_name=display_name, project=project_id, location=location,
    )

    print(endpoint.display_name)
    print(endpoint.resource_name)
    return endpoint

def deploy_model(project_id, location, model_id):
    model_location = "projects/{}/locations/{}/models/{}".format(project_id, location, model_id)

    print("Initializing Vertex AI")
    aiplatform.init(project=project_id, location=location)

    print("Getting model from {}".format(model_location))
    model = aiplatform.Model(model_location)

    print("Creating endpoint.")
    endpoint = create_endpoint(project_id, "{}_endpoint".format(model_id), location)

    print("Deploying endpoint")
    endpoint.deploy(
        model,
        machine_type="n1-standard-4",
        min_replica_count=1,
        max_replica_count=5,
        accelerator_type='NVIDIA_TESLA_K80',
        accelerator_count=1
    )

    return endpoint

endpoint = deploy_model(
    "<project name>",
    "us-central1",
    "<model id>",
)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code, I receive this error after the endpoint.deploy is triggered:
`google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 'dedicated_resources' is not supported for Model...` followed by the model location.

Note the places I've swapped my values with <***> to hide my local workspace variables.

Comment: Which statement is throwing the error?

Comment: The deploy statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encounter the error since it is not possible to assign a custom machine to a Text Classification model. Only custom models and AutoML tabular models can use custom machines as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/configure-compute#specify). For AutoML models aside from tabular models, Vertex AI automatically configures the machine type.

> If you want to use a custom-trained model or an AutoML tabular model
> to serve online predictions, you must specify a machine type when you
> deploy the Model resource as a DeployedModel to an Endpoint. **For other**
> **types of AutoML models, Vertex AI configures the machine types**
> **automatically.**

The workaround for this is to remove the machine related parameters on your `endpoint.deploy()` and you should be able to deploy the model.

```
print("Deploying endpoint")
endpoint.deploy(model)
```

Comment: I reread the documentation this morning and saw that all of the other parameters are optional. I tried without those values and it unblocked it. Thanks for sharing the links to the documentation. There are so many versions of it and tutorials out there, it sometimes feels like you have to accidentally come across important details like this.