# Vertex Ai issue when deploying a model using Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

This is what I use to deploy an Auto-ML model:

```
            MachineSpec machineSpec = MachineSpec.newBuilder().setMachineType("n1-standard-2").build();
            DedicatedResources dedicatedResources =
                    DedicatedResources.newBuilder().setMinReplicaCount(1).setMachineSpec(machineSpec).build();            
            String model = ModelName.of(project, location, modelId).toString();
            DeployedModel deployedModel =
                    DeployedModel.newBuilder()
                            .setModel(model)
                            .setDisplayName(deployedModelDisplayName)
                            .setDedicatedResources(dedicatedResources)
                            .build();
            Map<String, Integer> trafficSplit = new HashMap<>();
            trafficSplit.put("0", 100);
            EndpointName endpoint = EndpointName.of(project, location, endpointId);
            OperationFuture<DeployModelResponse, DeployModelOperationMetadata> response =
                    client.deployModelAsync(endpoint, deployedModel, trafficSplit);
            response.getInitialFuture().get().getName());
```

The error appears when I hit this line `response.getInitialFuture().get().getName());`

Here is the error:
`INVALID_ARGUMENT: 'dedicated_resources' is not supported for Model projects/***/locations/us-central1/models/***`

I can deploy the model using cloud console but not programmatically using java 8. It is a new model and the endpoint is also new without any assigned model to it.

Comment: Have you check that both the model and the dedicated resource share the same region? (us-central1) Also, thats the only error message you get? there is nothing above the error message that triggers before??

Comment: Yes they are both `us-central1`.  Nothing above that and that is the only error I get:
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: 'dedicated_resources' is not supported for Model projects/***/locations/us-central1/models/***
 at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552) at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:533)
 at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:86)
`

Comment: @Mahdi What AutoML model are you deploying (eg. Vision, Text, Tables, etc.)?

Comment: they are images (vision), and as I mentioned I could do all the tasks using Java8 such as creating the dataset, training the model, and creating the endpoint; the only one that does not work and it gives me this error is deploying a model to an endpoint.

Comment: Have you try deploying without specifying the machinetype ( using default )?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Vertex AI - 400 'dedicated\_resources' is not supported for Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577270/google-cloud-vertex-ai-400-dedicated-resources-is-not-supported-for-model)

Comment: @Bejens, yes I completely removed the machine type and resource type and tried the default one and the same error.

Comment: @Doni I followed exactly what is written in GCP documentation for Java Api in vertexai and I use n1-standard-2. The issue is not Machine Type related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry everyone, I was implementing the wrong section of the documentation. I had to follow AutoML image, not Custom-trained one.

[image]